# tkinter update interface after button press

Tags: python, tkinter

Hello overflow community! I'm creating a personal information GUI interface for school and I have reached a roadblock. The program allows for you to input information for someone (a customer for example) and eventually will allow for you to edit information and remove a person entirely, but here's what I have so far...

```
class CrudMain:

    def __init__(self, master, cust):
        self.master = master
        self.customer_list = cust

        cust_frame = Frame(self.master)
        frame = Frame(self.master)
        frame.master.title("Contact List Editor")

        self.label_1 = Label(frame, text='Contact list').pack(side=LEFT)

        r = 0
        for key in cust:
            Button(cust_frame, text=key, command=partial(self.cust_info, key)) .grid(row=1, column=r)
            r += 1

        self.add_button = Button(frame, text='Add Contact', command=self.add_contact_window)

        self.add_button.pack(anchor='sw')
        frame.pack(anchor='nw')
        cust_frame.pack(anchor='w')

    def add_contact_window(self):
        AddWindow(self.master, self.customer_list)

    def cust_info(self, key):
        CustInfo(self.master, self.customer_list, key)


class CustInfo:

    def __init__(self, master, cust, key):
        self.master = master
        self.cust = cust[key]
        self.info_window = Toplevel()
        self.info_window.title("Contact Information")

        Label(self.info_window, text=self.cust['first_name']).pack()
        Label(self.info_window, text=self.cust['last_name']).pack()
        Label(self.info_window, text=self.cust['email']).pack()
        Label(self.info_window, text=self.cust['address']).pack()
        Label(self.info_window, text=self.cust['phone']).pack()

        Button(self.info_window, text='Close', command=self.info_window.destroy).pack(anchor='s')


class AddWindow:

    def __init__(self, master, cust):
        self.master = master
        self.cust = cust

        self.add_window = Toplevel()
        self.add_window.title("Add Contact")
        Label(self.add_window, text='First Name: ').grid(row=0, column=0)
        Label(self.add_window, text='Last Name: ').grid(row=1, column=0)
        Label(self.add_window, text='Email Address: ').grid(row=2, column=0)
        Label(self.add_window, text='Living Address: ').grid(row=3, column=0)
        Label(self.add_window, text='Phone Number:').grid(row=4, column=0)

        self.first_name = StringVar()
        self.last_name = StringVar()
        self.email = StringVar()
        self.address = StringVar()
        self.phone = StringVar()

        Button(self.add_window, text="Submit", command=lambda: self.save(self.cust)).grid(row=5, column=0)
        Button(self.add_window, text='Cancel', command=self.add_window.destroy).grid(row=5, column=1)

        Entry(self.add_window, textvariable=self.first_name).grid(row=0, column=1)
        Entry(self.add_window, textvariable=self.last_name).grid(row=1, column=1)
        Entry(self.add_window, textvariable=self.email).grid(row=2, column=1)
        Entry(self.add_window, textvariable=self.address).grid(row=3, column=1)
        Entry(self.add_window, textvariable=self.phone).grid(row=4, column=1)

    def save(self, customers):
        name = str(self.first_name.get())
        last = str(self.last_name.get())
        email = str(self.email.get())
        address = str(self.address.get())
        phone = str(self.phone.get())

        save = {'first_name': name, 'last_name': last, 'email': email, 'address': address, 'phone': phone}
        key = save['first_name']
        customers[key] = save
        pickle.dump(customers, open('customer_file.dat', 'wb'))
        messagebox.showinfo("Status", "Information saved successfully!")


    def main():
        try:
            input_file = open("customer_file.dat", "rb")
            customers = pickle.load(input_file)
        except (FileNotFoundError, IOError):
            customers = collections.OrderedDict()

    root = Tk()
    CrudMain(root, customers)
    root.mainloop()

    main()
```

Question is, how do I make it so after the user presses the submit button once all the information is in the entry field, the program updates and shows another button with the new user? Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add meaningful code and a problem description here.  Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment you are missing a method to update the existing customer buttons. I've modified your code to create an `update_customers` method to both initially create the buttons and to 'redraw' the buttons when a new person is added. 
I also modified your code to destroy the Add Contact Window once a new person's details are added.

```
from tkinter import *
import collections
import pickle
from functools import partial

class CrudMain:

    def __init__(self, master, cust):
        self.master = master
        self.customer_list = cust

        self.cust_frame = Frame(self.master)
        frame = Frame(self.master)
        frame.master.title("Contact List Editor")

        self.label_1 = Label(frame, text='Contact list').pack(side=LEFT)

        self.update_customers()

        self.add_button = Button(frame, text='Add Contact', command=self.add_contact_window)

        self.add_button.pack(anchor='sw')
        frame.pack(anchor='nw')
        self.cust_frame.pack(anchor='w')

    def update_customers(self):
        for widget in self.cust_frame.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()

        r = 0
        for key in self.customer_list:
            Button(self.cust_frame, text=key, command=partial(self.cust_info, key)) .grid(row=1, column=r)
            r += 1


    def add_contact_window(self):
        AddWindow(self.master, self , self.customer_list)

    def cust_info(self, key):
        CustInfo(self.master, self.customer_list, key)


class CustInfo:

    def __init__(self, master, cust, key):
        self.master = master
        self.cust = cust[key]
        self.info_window = Toplevel()
        self.info_window.title("Contact Information")

        Label(self.info_window, text=self.cust['first_name']).pack()
        Label(self.info_window, text=self.cust['last_name']).pack()
        Label(self.info_window, text=self.cust['email']).pack()
        Label(self.info_window, text=self.cust['address']).pack()
        Label(self.info_window, text=self.cust['phone']).pack()

        Button(self.info_window, text='Close', command=self.info_window.destroy).pack(anchor='s')


class AddWindow:

    def __init__(self, master, main_window, cust):
        self.master = master
        self.cust = cust
        self.main_window = main_window

        self.add_window = Toplevel()
        self.add_window.title("Add Contact")
        Label(self.add_window, text='First Name: ').grid(row=0, column=0)
        Label(self.add_window, text='Last Name: ').grid(row=1, column=0)
        Label(self.add_window, text='Email Address: ').grid(row=2, column=0)
        Label(self.add_window, text='Living Address: ').grid(row=3, column=0)
        Label(self.add_window, text='Phone Number:').grid(row=4, column=0)

        self.first_name = StringVar()
        self.last_name = StringVar()
        self.email = StringVar()
        self.address = StringVar()
        self.phone = StringVar()

        Button(self.add_window, text="Submit", command=lambda: self.save(self.cust)).grid(row=5, column=0)
        Button(self.add_window, text='Cancel', command=self.add_window.destroy).grid(row=5, column=1)

        Entry(self.add_window, textvariable=self.first_name).grid(row=0, column=1)
        Entry(self.add_window, textvariable=self.last_name).grid(row=1, column=1)
        Entry(self.add_window, textvariable=self.email).grid(row=2, column=1)
        Entry(self.add_window, textvariable=self.address).grid(row=3, column=1)
        Entry(self.add_window, textvariable=self.phone).grid(row=4, column=1)

    def save(self, customers):
        name = str(self.first_name.get())
        last = str(self.last_name.get())
        email = str(self.email.get())
        address = str(self.address.get())
        phone = str(self.phone.get())

        save = {'first_name': name, 'last_name': last, 'email': email, 'address': address, 'phone': phone}
        key = save['first_name']
        customers[key] = save
        pickle.dump(customers, open('customer_file.dat', 'wb'))
        messagebox.showinfo("Status", "Information saved successfully!")
        self.add_window.destroy()
        self.main_window.update_customers()


def main():
    try:
        input_file = open("customer_file.dat", "rb")
        customers = pickle.load(input_file)
    except (FileNotFoundError, IOError):
        customers = collections.OrderedDict()

    root = Tk()
    CrudMain(root, customers)
    root.mainloop()

main()
```

Comment: Works perfectly. thank you so much. very smart way of going about it i definitely would not have thought about it that way. still very new to Tkinter and not sure how everything works with each other.